# R exporting Kmeans clustering results into excel

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

i've run my kmeans test from an excel data source and now want to get he results out in excel. I've tried the following code but all i get is a blank worksheet. I'm relatively new to R so i imagine its something simple that I'm missing - please help!

```
set.seed(123)
kmeansresults<-kmeans(df[,7], 5, iter.max = 50, nstart = 100)
x<-kmeansresults$clusters
write.csv(x, "clustering results.csv")
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to be in this excel file? There is no `$clusters` item but there is a `$cluster` item (no s). That just contains a numeric cluster ID. Is that all you want to save?

Comment: im trying to export the clustering vector into an excel file

Comment: You can separate the cluster data e.g. using `clusters <- x$cluster`. You can then add the cluster to the original dataframe using `cbind(df,clusters)`, and write csv using the newly expanded df.

Comment: @MrFlick yes thats all i wanted to do and your solution worked :-) many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
data("USArrests")
m <- scale(USArrests)

set.seed(123)
km_res <- kmeans(m, 4, nstart=25)
x <- km_res$cluster

write.csv(x, "/Users/user/Desktop/foo.csv")
```

I guess your problem was not writing a CSV file but calling `km_res$clusters` that should be `km_res$cluster`. In `R` you can access the structure of an object as `str(km_res)` to see what is "inside". There is no slot `clusters` but `cluster`.